# Her Drinking/Drinking too much caused the coughs. - both correct?

Tags: meaning, discourse-context

‎A: She's coughing non-stop.

**Example 1**
B: Her drinking too much caused the coughs.

**Example 2**
B: Drinking too much caused the coughs.

Are both example one and example two suitable for this case?

My thought is that example one specifically says who did the drinking.

Example two said that the drinking as an action caused the coughing. But I think with the context example two actually has the same meaning as example one.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Usually the OP describes his or her efforts to answer the question before asking others to make such efforts.

Comment: For the feminine version as given, the actual syntax is "ambiguous". For the *masculine* version, we have to choose between ***Him** drinking too much...* and ***His** drinking too much...* The meaning is the same regardless of the pronoun, but I'd say the "possessive" *(**his**)* is probably more common in such contexts. In OP's specific example, the implied subject is obvious anyway, so both versions will be understood as meaning the same thing. How to express it is essentially a stylistic choice.

Comment: This isn't directly related to what you're asking, but when the word **cough** refers to a *condition* (even a temporary one), it is more often used in the **singular** form. The plural **coughs** is only used to refer to multiple individual "instances." For example, "She has **a cough** (singular)," or "We heard many coughs and sneezes coming from the next room (plural)." The sentences in your question could refer to **either** "having *a cough*" or to "producing *multiple coughs,*" but if you intend the first, it should be singular.

Answer (score -1):

You are absolutely correct. Both are acceptable. Example 1 specifies exactly who is doing the drinking, although most people will assume it's her drinking. That gives rise to this joke:

> Doctor: I can't find a vein to make the injection. It's because of the drinking.
>
> Patient: But I don't drink?
>
> Doctor: No, I'm too drunk to see the vein.